# QSettings mac and plist files

Tags: macos, qt, plist, qsettings

I store my settings using `QSettings` class and sometimes, it gives me a strange behavior.

I use this to add a value :

```
QSettings _settings("MyCompany", "AppName")
_settings.setValue("lastfile", "SomeString");
```

And this to remove all values :

```
QStringList indexes = _settings.allKeys();
foreach(QString index, indexes)
    _settings->remove(index);
```

And it seems to work randomly. Sometimes it add or remove the value to the `.plist` file (I checked it using `_settings.fileName()`) and sometimes nothing change.

My question, which is kind of implicit, is **what am I missing and how to make it work normally**?

Comment: Have you set the format? QSettings::setDefaultFormat(QSettings::NativeFormat)

Comment: @Merlin069 once again, you got it right, make an answer, you'll get +25 rep ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the format with: -

```
QSettings::setDefaultFormat(QSettings::NativeFormat);
```